# Error promoting Windows Server 2022 to Domain Controller

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, domain-controller, windows-server-2019, windows-server-2022

I have a virtual Windows 2022 Server in a VMWare ESXi environment, and a WS2019 virtual in another host, which is my Active Directory Domain Controller. I've been trying to promote the WS2022 to domain controller, but it fails during the process with a "The remote procedure call failed" error, then the computers in network cant log on the domain and I have to restart the WS2019 in DSRM and activate the NTDS instance to solve it, every time the promotion fails.

I have tried disabling the firewalls  but it still gives the remote procedure call failed.

[This is the error that appears, from PowerShell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tnG8.png) Tried from Server Management with same results.

What could be the cause? Is there some configuration in the Virtual Network Adapter from the VMWare that  I'm missing?

Comment: Run `nltest /dsgetdc:domainname.com /server:WS2019` from the 2022 server. Also PortQueryUI. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24009

Comment: @GregAskew the nltest completed with these flags: PDC GC DS LDAP KDC TIMESERV GTIMESERV WRITABLE DNS_DC DNS_DOMAIN DNS_FOREST CLOSE_SITE FULL_SECRET WS DS_8 DS_9 DS_10 KEYLIST; the PortQuery returned as not listening port 42, and as listening or filtered the 138, 88, 389

Comment: `computers in network cant log on the domain and I have to restart the WS2019 in DSRM and activate the NTDS instance to solve it`. That should never be necessary. I've never heard of doing that. How are you "disabling the firewalls"?

Comment: @GregAskew What I meant about the computers is that after de promotion fails, if I try to log from any computer it will stay in loading configuration screen for hours without advancing. About the firewall, I go to Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Customize Settings and turn off every Windows Defender Firewall, and the antivirus in the current DC,